# how to pick exact timestamps from a column

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a table like this and I want to filter a row with exact timestamp.

```
 +------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
|job_id|timestamp                   |input_values      |inputA|inputB|inputC|
+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
|job1  |2023-03-01T19:12:58.000+0000|[0.12, 0.34, 0.23]|0.12  |0.34  |0.23  |
|job2  |2023-03-01T19:12:59.000+0000|[0.23, 0.55, 0.12]|0.23  |0.55  |0.12  |
|job3  |2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.12, 0.32]|0.23  |0.12  |0.32  |
|job4  |2023-03-01T19:13:01.000+0000|[0.23, 0.12, 0.32]| 0.45 | 0.34 |  0.34|                
+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
```

and I want to pick only a timestamp with exact hour(ex)2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000), in a real table there are so many timestamp rows and I need to pick all that kind of timestamps.

How can I do this using pyspark?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean exact timestamp (2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000) or exact hour of the timestamp (i.e. 19)? It would help if you could add expected output

Answer (score 0):

For demo, This is my sample DataFrame named 'df':

[image]

If you want to exact hour of the timestamp use filter :

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour
hr_df = df.filter(hour(df.timestamp) == 19)
display(hr_df)
```

[image]